# User gets multiple email notification

Tags: php, mysql

I have a code that update a table and send email notification after a record is update.
It is a leave approval system where registered members login to apply for the leave. This code sends emails to two users (employee) and (employee manager)when you try to approve or reject the leave request.

When there three people apply for leave and you try to approve for one user,the user get email notification 3 times.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$serverName;Database=$database", $user, $pass);

?>


<?php
require_once './config.php';
include './header.php';

?>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <?php
function mssql_escape($str) {
    return str_replace("'", "''", $str);
}
filter_var($_SESSION['kt_login_user'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
$email =  $_SESSION['kt_login_user'];
$empID = $row['No_'];
$year = date("Y");
$sql = 'SELECT
dbo.[Leave Request].[timestamp],
dbo.[Leave Request].leave_type,
dbo.[Leave Request].date_applied,
dbo.[Leave Request].start_date AS start,
dbo.[Leave Request].end_date AS resume,
dbo.[Leave Request].supervisor,
dbo.[Leave Request].supAprrove_date,
dbo.[Leave Request].leave_reason,
dbo.[Leave Request].reject_reason,
dbo.[Leave Request].[year],
dbo.[Leave Request].partner,
dbo.[Leave Request].partnerAprrove_date,
dbo.[Leave Request].id,
dbo.[Leave Request].phone,
dbo.[Leave Request].total_left,
dbo.[Leave Request].supAprrove,
dbo.[Leave Request].partnerApprove,
dbo.[Leave Request].leave_days,
dbo.[Cost Center].Description AS cost,
dbo.[First Category Level].[First Level] AS dept,
dbo.[Leave Request].email,
dbo.[Employee].[First Name],
dbo.[Employee].[Middle Name],
dbo.[Employee].[Last Name],
dbo.[Employee].No_,
dbo.[Employee].[Job Titles],
dbo.[Employee].[Employment Date],
dbo.[Employee].[Birth Date],
dbo.[Leave].Description AS leave,
dbo.[Leave].[Maximum Days],
dbo.[Supervisor List].[Supervisor Name],
dbo.[Supervisor List].[Supervisor Email],
dbo.[Partner List].[Employee Name],
dbo.[Partner List].email AS partMail

FROM
dbo.[Leave Request]
LEFT JOIN dbo.[Cost Center] ON dbo.[Leave Request].cost_centre = dbo.[Cost Center].Code
LEFT JOIN dbo.[First Category Level] ON dbo.[Leave Request].dept = dbo.[First Category Level].Code
LEFT JOIN dbo.[Employee] ON dbo.[Leave Request].email = dbo.[Employee].[Company E-Mail]
LEFT JOIN dbo.[Leave] ON dbo.[Leave Request].leave_type = dbo.[Leave].Code
LEFT JOIN dbo.[Supervisor List] ON dbo.[Leave Request].supervisor = dbo.[Supervisor List].[Supervisor ID]
left JOIN dbo.[Partner List] ON dbo.[Leave Request].partner = dbo.[Partner List].[Employee No]

WHERE
dbo.[Leave Request].supAprrove = \'pending\'
AND dbo.[Leave Request].supervisor=\''.mssql_escape($email).'\'';
$leave = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
$id = $data['id'];
?>

     <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                 <th>Start Date</th>
                <th>Resumption Date</th>
              <th>Leave Days Requested</th>
              <th>Leave Days Left</th>
                <th>Leave Days Entitled</th>
                <th>Type of Leave</th>
                <th>Department</th>
                <th>Cost Centre</th>
                <th>Year</th>

                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
           <?php while ($data = sqlsrv_fetch_array($leave)) {?>
     <tr>
                <td><a href="sup_approval.php?id=<?php echo $data['id'];?>">.</a>  <?php echo $data['First Name'].' '.$data['Middle Name'];  ?></td>
                <td><?php echo date_format($data['start'],'d-m-Y');  ?></td>
                <td><?php echo date_format($data['resume'],'d-m-Y');  ?></td>
                <td><?php echo intval($data['leave_days']);  ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data['total_left'];  ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data['Maximum Days'];  ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data['leave'];  ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data['dept'];  ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data['cost'];  ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data['year'];  ?></td>

                <td>
  <?php 
  require_once './config.php';
if (isset($_POST["sub"])) {
  require_once "phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php";
//Connect to MySQL and create our PDO object.
$pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$serverName;Database=$database", $user, $pass);

//Our UPDATE SQL statement.
if ($_POST['supAprrove']==='approved'){$usql = 'UPDATE dbo.[Leave Request] SET dbo.[Leave Request].supAprrove_date = :adate,dbo.[Leave Request].supAprrove=:approve,dbo.[Leave Request].partnerApprove = \'pending\' WHERE id = :id';}
elseif ($_POST['supAprrove']==='rejected') {$usql = 'UPDATE dbo.[Leave Request] SET dbo.[Leave Request].supAprrove_date = :adate,dbo.[Leave Request].supAprrove=:approve, dbo.[Leave Request].partnerApprove = \'rejected\' WHERE id = :id';}
//Prepare our UPDATE SQL statement.
$statement = $pdo->prepare($usql);

//The Primary Key of the row that we want to update.
$id = $_POST['lid'];

//The new model value.
$adate = date('Y-m-d');

//The new model value.
$approve = $_POST['supAprrove'];

//Bind our value to the parameter :id.
$statement->bindValue(':id', $id);

//Bind our :model parameter.
$statement->bindValue(':approve', $approve);

//Bind our :model parameter.
$statement->bindValue(':adate', $adate);

//Execute our UPDATE statement.
$update = $statement->execute();

///send mail

$partMail = $_POST[partMail];
$empName = $_POST[ename];
$lemail = $data['email'];
$fname = $data['First Name'];


        $message = '<html><head>
                <title>Leave Request Application</title>
                </head>
                <body>';



        $message .= '<h1>Leave Request</h1>';
        $message .= '<p><strong>'.$fname.'</strong> has '.$_POST[leave_days].' day(s) of leave '.$_POST[supAprrove].' by his/her supervisor/manager.</p>';
        $message .= '<p>Leave start date <strong>'.date_format(date_create($_POST[start_date]),'d-m-Y').'</strong></p>';
        $message .= '<p> Resumption date <strong>'.date_format(date_create($_POST[end_date]),'d-m-Y').'</strong></p>';
        $message .= '<p>Leave reason: <strong>'.$_POST[leave_reason].'</strong></p>';
        $message .= '<p>Phone Number: <strong>'.$_POST[phone].'</strong></p>';
        $message .= '<p>Please login into Amanfo via this link <a href="'.SITE_URL.'part_pending_leave.php"> to Approve or Reject Leave Request</a>';
        $message .= '<p>Thank you.</p>';
        $message .= '<h3>HR.</h3>';
        $message .= "</body></html>";


        // php mailer code starts
        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
        $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
        $mail->Mailer = "smtp";

        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
        $mail->SMTPAuth = false;                  // enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
        $mail->Host = "******";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
        $mail->Port = 25;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server

        $mail->Username = '*****'; //admin email address
        $mail->Password = '*****';                    // admin email password



        $mail->Subject = trim("Leave Request");
        $mail->MsgHTML($message);

// php mailer code starts
        $mail2 = new PHPMailer(true);
        $mail2->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
        $mail2->Mailer = "smtp";

        $mail2->SMTPDebug = 0;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
        $mail2->SMTPAuth = false;                  // enable SMTP authentication
        $mail2->SMTPSecure = "";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
        $mail2->Host = "******";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
        $mail2->Port = 25;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server

        $mail2->Username = '*******'; //admin email address
        $mail2->Password = '******';                      // admin email password


        $mail2->SetFrom('*****', 'HR Department');
        $mail2->AddAddress($lemail);

        $mail2->Subject = "Leave ".$_POST['supAprrove']." by Supervisor";
        $mail2->MsgHTML($message);






        try {

// now send to user.
$mail2->AddAddress($lemail);
//$mail2->AltBody    = ""; // optional, comment out and test


$mail2->Body = "Hello <b>".$fname."</b>, Your leave request has been <b>".$_POST['supAprrove']."</b> by Supervisor";
$mail2->Send();

          if ($_POST['supAprrove']==='rejected'){echo ""; }else {$mail->send();}
          $msg = "You have ".$_POST['supAprrove']." the application, the requestor has been notified";
          header('Location: pending_leave.php?msg');
          $msgType = "success";
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
          $msg = $ex->getMessage();
          $msgType = "warning";
        }


     $insertGoTo = "pending_leave.php?msg"; 
     header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));


    }


    ?>

    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="pending_leave.php">
      <label>
      <select name="supAprrove" autofocus class="textBox" id="supAprrove" >
      <option value="approved">Approve</option> 
      <option value="rejected">Reject</option>
      </select>

      </label>
      <input name="supAprrove_date" type="hidden" id="supAprrove_date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" />
      <input type="hidden" name="lid" id="lid"  value="<?php echo $data['id'];  ?>"/>

      <input type="hidden" name="supName" id="supName" value="<?php echo $data['Supervisor Name'];  ?>" />
      <input type="hidden" name="partMail" id="partMail"  value="<?php echo $data['partner'];  ?>"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="leave_days" id="leave_days"  value="<?php echo intval($data['leave_days']);  ?>"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="start_date" id="start_date"  value="<?php echo date_format($data['start'],'d-m-Y');  ?>"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="end_date" id="end_date"  value="<?php echo date_format($data['resume'],'d-m-Y');  ?>"/>
      <input type="text" name="leave_reason" id="leave_reason"  value="<?php echo $data['leave_reason'];  ?>" size="20"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="phone" id="phone"  value="<?php echo $data['phone'];  ?>"/>
      <input name="ename" type="hidden" id="ename" value="<?php echo $data['First Name'].' '.$data['First Name'].' '.$data['Middle Name'];  ?>" />
      <label>
      <input type="submit" name="sub" id="button" value="Submit" />
      </label>
    </form>
  </td>
     </tr><?php }?>
        </tbody>
    </table>   
    <?php if ($msg <> "") { ?>
  <div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-<?php echo $msgType; ?>">
    <button data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">x</button>
    <p><?php echo $msg; ?></p>
  </div>
<?php } ?> 
</div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Sorry, but your code is a mess. You have two lines of `require_once './config.php';`, you never define `$data` in your code. you have syntax errors in these lines `$partMail = $_POST[partMail];` and `$empName = $_POST[ename];`. Please edit your post, remove irrelevant lines and create a [mcve version](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code so we can actually read and understand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you make form submission unique by doing something?
Like following

```
$my_index = "sub_".$data['id'];
if (isset($_POST[$my_index])) {
.............
.............
}
```

and in your form

```
<input type="submit" name="sub_<?php echo $data['id']; ?>" id="button" value="Submit" />
```

See the result, if any changes or not.
Make your form submission unique. I think that is the problem here.